# Why do Late Answers always show up in the First Post review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

In the event that a new user posts a late answer to a question [Like this review I had](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7312374), why are they never sent to the Late Answer queue?

I've had countless first post answers to old questions that go into the First Post queue, but never into the Late Answer queue.

I suppose technically this is both a late answer and a first post, but the "Late Answer" queue clearly states it is to

> Review late answers from new users

Arugably, a new user posting an answer on an old question would quite frequently be a first answer, since they're a new user.

I feel like the Late Answer queue is almost always empty (as mentioned before) while the First Post queue is frequently populated.

I'd submit that these first post (but also late answer) posts should go into the Late Answer queue where they belong and help loyal reviewers make some progress toward that seemingly impossible badge.

Comment: How do you know they never go to Late Answers?  Maybe they go to both and you just don't see it in Late Answers?  (I actually don't know the logic - just theorizing)

Comment: I usually check the review queues and if there is every anything at all in the Late Answer queue I'll go there first. This particular instance, there was (as usual) nothing in the Late answer but some 10-15 in First Post, which is where this review came from.

Comment: In my experience there are always a lot of users "waiting" for review and the queues that do not have a lot of questions often get reviewed very quickly.  I think it is equally likely that you just don't see them.  In fact [Duplicate Low Quality Post in First Post & Late Answer - Double Flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157262/duplicate-low-quality-post-in-first-post-late-answer-double-flag) suggests that is designed to push to both.  Although the design may have chanced since then and the answer was never updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On at least half a dozen occasions I have deliberately Skipped a late answer from First Posts, then reloaded Late Answers to pick it up, in order to run through my LA cap a little faster*. So I can vouch that they do and will show up in either queue. However, whichever queue grabs it first will lock it in for several minutes, and FP grabs it a distressing percentage of the time.

Note that a while ago, [LA's cutoff was raised to include more posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue) from users with up to 50 rep, but FP did not receive any similar adjustment, so LA is no longer a proper subset.

Answer (score 5):

Posts can be in multiple queues at the same time if they match the criteria of those queues. Your post *is* a late answer, so it was in the late answers review queue.

I went ahead and fished out the [review from the late answers queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/7312513). There is only a 7 second second difference between the two completed reviews which suggests that the task was pushed into both queues at the same time. It's unlikely that you get to review the same post in both review queues, because it may be reviewed by somebody else in one queue when you do your review of the same post in the other queue.

I used the [history link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/history) to find the other review. It contains all reviews for 10k users not just their own. If it is an older post you're inquiring, you can check in which queues it was handled by using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203969/find-the-reviewtasks-for-a-post) in the data explorer.

Comment: What do you mean by "Posts can be in multiple queues at the same time. " and "It's unlikely to get the same post in both review queues."

Comment: @Trisped Since you're reviewing in one queue, you would have to have the other queue open in another tab, but who does that? Besides, this might be blocked by the system.

Comment: @Trisped I think is point is that while any on equestion/answer may be in two review queues at the same time, the likelihood of YOU personally running into the same question via reviewing late answer and then reviewing first posts is highly unlikely.

Comment: Oh, so you are saying "It is unlikely that it will be reviewed from both queues at the same time."

Comment: @Trisped leigero is right. I hope it is clear now.